# ping federate: SSO over http - Page Expired

Tags: pingfederate

I had PingFederate server IdP-initiated SSO configured to use HTTPS. After switching to HTTP (Server settings/My base URL) I started receiving **Page Expired** error from Ping.

Do you have an idea why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PingFederate uses the combination of a nonce inserted into the resume URL and the value of a cookie (PF) set with the initial response to store the user state while trying to authenticate the user. ([Ping Identity Knowledge-base Article](https://ping.force.com/Support/PingIdentityArticle?id=kA3400000008SPxCAM))

By default the PF cookie is set with a [secure flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_cookie), meaning that the browser won't send it to non-HTTPS resources. This setting can be changed by editing the */server/default/data/config-store/session-cookie-config.xml* file and setting the *cookie-secure-flag* to false. This would require PingFederate to be restarted.